# Can you make the reputation graph points clickable?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, reputation-graph

That's such a useful graph in the reputation tab.

Is there any way you can make the individual points that make up the graph clickable (to see the activity for that one day)? As my days here grow, it is getting harder and harder to select a one-day range. Typing in the range manually is too much trouble (lazy).

When I see an unusual increase in my reputation, I like to see what post(s) contributed to the score. It is hard to drag around one individual point to create a small range. It would be nice if selecting the point created a one-day range.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

This was asking about a different graph, but this can now be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as you now get exactly what the OP asked for by clicking on a column.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe have a Calendar Control or Date Picker, so you can just mouseclick to select the exact day.