# Clickable interface to monthly rep bar graph?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, reputation-graph

When you hover over the monthly reputation barchart, it shows you how many points were earned on the day that you're hovering over.  Which leads one to want to click.  Which does nothing.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to make this link to a search returning all your activity on that day?

This has been asked before on the old graph, but I cannot find where it has been asked on the new graph (where it would be more useful anyway, because you can actually identify the right bar to click on).

[Can you make the reputation graph points clickable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/can-you-make-the-reputation-graph-points-clickable)

Comment: I agree that it is slightly misleading, but not that it necessarily needs fixing.

Comment: There should be the words in grey "mouseover each bar to see details". Else it just looks like a bar graph truncated by a table below it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the reputation tab of your profile, select [the "graph" sub tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636656/ari-b-friedman?tab=reputation&sort=graph). That is clickable, and it shows a break up of your day's plunders at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'm aware.  I just found it odd that the monthly isn't clickable since it's so much more prominent.

Comment: @ari looks like a whole load of extra JS to put for something that most people won't use. You can go to the rep graph in two clicks--I, personally am satisfied with it.